# Running as an admin, is it possible to create a non-administrative scheduled task?

Tags: windows, command-line, security, scheduled-tasks, uac

I'm working on a project responsible for establishing three callbacks for the execution of commands. These are supposed to represent three different scenarios: Regular Command Prompt, Administrative Command Prompt and SYSTEM Command Prompt.

I've opted for the creation of these routines in the form of Scheduled Tasks, as that allows for easier upkeeping and maintenance.

The problem here is that I need to create all of the three callbacks at the same time (these are created using an installer application), meaning I require the installer to be ran with administrative rights. While both the SYSTEM Command Prompt and the Administrative Command Prompt work flawlessly, the Regular Command Prompt still shows up with administrative permissions.

Current Task Configuration:

[image: Current Task Configuration]

I thought unmarking "Run with highest privileges" would mean the Command Prompt to be ran under non-administrative context, but it doesn't seem to work that way. Is there a way to achieve this with an administrative user that doesn't involve the usage of another account?

Comment: If UAC is off, removing the checkbox "Run with highest privileges" has no effect, the task action will run elevated. So in that case, turn on UAC and put the lever to the highest position, restart the computer and retry.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a scheduled task as non-admin but there are a few things you need to consider.

The user you are running as cannot be admin. If the lucas user is your own user that has admin privileges, create a new user on your system with different credentials, ensure it is not admin and use that user instead.

Second, you need to store the user credentials in the task, otherwise it won't work correctly.

The run with highest privileges should be turned off.

Keep in mind that you are talking about an installer here, if the installer does not have permission to write in any of the folders it needs to as non-admin, the task will not work. For example, the currently logged in user's appdata folder is off limits for all other non-admin users, including the one for this task, unless it is specifically installed in this non-admin's appdata folder. Program Files and may other folders on the C drive are also off-limits for non-admins, which is why you often need to install a program as administrator on your home computer.

So ensure that the folder you write to has write rights for non-admin users, or install as SYSTEM user instead.